# Generate element dynamically using angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular

button when clicked inject a html markup that represent new product name and quantity to be added to the cart. After the client submit the form i want those product stored in an array of object.

The problem i faced is angular 6 security that hide some html tag like input.

Trying to bypass this security issue i create a Pipe called SafePipe that transform html to DomSenitizer

```
<div [innerHTML]="htmltobeadded | safe>
```

this worked fine in the template like this.

Inside the button method i used javascript to inject the htmltobeadd and the security issue came again.

```
document.getElementById("add").innerHTML = htmltobeadded
```

I use safePipe.transform() to transfrom my html to Domsenitizer

```
safehtml = safepipe.tranform(htmltobeadded)
```

and used

```
document.getElementById("add").innerHTML = safehtml
```

Error: safehtml is not assignable to type string

Answer (score 1):

> Error: safehtml is not assignable to type string

You can just cast is to `any`:

```
document.getElementById("add").innerHTML = safehtml as any
```